# Trouble calling instance variables in Python

Tags: python, class, object, python-2.7, instance-variables

I'm just starting to learn my way around classes now and I came across something I don't understand. Let's say I have a class...

```
class Area(object):
    def __init__(self, name, items):
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
```

Now if I initiate an instance of Area this way:

```
impala = Area("Impala", ["shotgun", "salt"])
```

and then call on a variable, say:

```
print impala.items
```

it works just fine. However, if I try to initiate it this way:

```
class impala(Area):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Impala"
        self.items = ["shotgun", "salt"]
```

and then try to do the same thing it gives me an error: "type object 'impala' has no attribute 'items'"

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong in the second example and why it's happening?

Comment: `class impala(Area)` does not create an instance of `Area`. It defines a subclass of `Area` called `impala`.

Comment: You never create an instance of your second class.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but it looks like you are confusing inheritance with instantiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same name for your class and variable. `impala` and `impala`, I would presume that Python is accessing the class, not the instance.

To avoid this, I recommend following [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for your variable names, giving classes names in `CapWords` and local variables `lowercase_with_underscores`. Naturally, you should also be careful when you name your items not to have two things with the same name in the same namespace.

```
>>> class Area(object):
...     def __init__(self, name, items):
...         self.name = name
...         self.items = items
... 
>>> class Impala(Area):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.name = "Impala"
...         self.items = ["shotgun", "salt"]
... 
>>> impala = Impala()
>>> impala.items
['shotgun', 'salt']
```

Comment: Ok so Impala is a sub-class and not an instance. Got it, thanks for the link!

Comment: @Lattyware.  Your explanation leaves out that Jen Camara was not creating an instance, which was the key issue.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I did not understand that was what he was trying to do, to be perfectly honest. I won't bother duplicating what has already been said in the comments now though.